# Facebook oauth2 login returns (400) bad request

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm converting my C# ASP.NET MVC 4 facebook login to a VB ASP.NET MVC 2 version project.

Unfortunately i am getting this error which i can't figure out what the problem is.

The main error: Bad Request 400 error.
More detailed error:

> WWW-Authenticate: OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_code" "Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request"

Controller:

```
<HttpPost> _
    <AllowAnonymous> _
    Public Function ExternalLogin(provider As String, returnUrl As String) As ActionResult
        Return New ExternalLoginResult(provider, Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", New With { _
            Key .ReturnUrl = returnUrl _
        }))
    End Function



    Public Function ExternalLoginCallback(returnUrl As String) As ActionResult
        Dim result As AuthenticationResult = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", New With { _
            Key .ReturnUrl = returnUrl _
        }))

        ' Eind resultaat krijg je hier
        If result.IsSuccessful Then
            ' Temporary Properties
            Dim strTempGeslacht As String = result.ExtraData("gender")



            ' Properties
            Dim strVoornaam As String = result.ExtraData("firstname")
            Dim strAchternaam As String = result.ExtraData("lastname")
            Dim strEmail As String = result.ExtraData("email")
            Dim strGeboortePlaats As String = result.ExtraData("hometown")
            Dim strWoonplaats As String = result.ExtraData("location")
            Dim arrayWerk As String() = result.ExtraData("work").Split("*"C)
            Dim intGeslacht As Integer = If(strTempGeslacht = "male", 0, 1)
            Dim intOpenID As Int64 = Int64.Parse(result.ProviderUserId)
            Dim CiDutch As New CultureInfo("nl-NL", False)
            Dim strBirthday As String = String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", result.ExtraData("birthday"))



            ' Redirect
            Return RedirectToAction("Facebook", "Bedankt")
        End If

        ' Error
        Return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home")
    End Function


    Friend Class ExternalLoginResult
        Inherits ActionResult
        Public Sub New(provider__1 As String, returnUrl__2 As String)
            Provider = provider__1
            ReturnUrl = "http://localhost:25806/Facebook/ExternalLoginCallback"
        End Sub

        Public Provider As String
        Public ReturnUrl As String

        Public Overrides Sub ExecuteResult(context As ControllerContext)
            OAuthWebSecurity.RequestAuthentication(Provider, ReturnUrl)
        End Sub
    End Class

End Class
```

Query Acces Token (the error occurs here when using downloadstring)

```
 protected override string QueryAccessToken(Uri returnUrl, string authorizationCode)
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            string url = string.Format("{0}?client_id={1}&client_secret={2}&redirect_uri={3}&code={4}", TokenEP, this._appId, this._appSecret, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(returnUrl.ToString()), authorizationCode);

            string content = client.DownloadString(url);

            NameValueCollection nameValueCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(content);
            if (nameValueCollection != null)
            {
                string result = nameValueCollection["access_token"];
                return result;
            }
            return null;

        }
```

Query url:

```
"https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=607648425938521&client_secret=ff099b80cc19da0ec0870df99fa465b0&redirect_uri=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a18774%2fvacatures%2fExternalLoginCallBack%3f__provider__%3dfacebook%26__sid__%3d3dda4b1db178404094cbeef339d414b9&code=AQAAHJ0UoPjqvtOLjgUJ7ipzY0j7-8FxoTx7nt_Vxq9FD0cN-DhVH8BclofFEXPsPU7Fm1YHKGSlJRcLGedHSA23sVpkbssBp5yQo3PmBkUSZ9LBuckKrkjagvz4HkgFQ_oX2DoEPDmpkKo8O97GYlBt7j185SncBcpmbi8I7DNs9Z8wGP_FGQb8Mh6iMz3SH4IB1Ae3OppthmRXEJOj9k7xiboPsAYTf3w7E6MhWU3uNnR-SfA5RkSXkLas7xUnKF7eqmPM9_3pAMj2ObOAA1e4dcKke-QABo_FGx7LV0OY1pEeKIbbu9Ag5h0SBqmGi9k
```

All the links are the same from the working project C# mvc 4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

6 Hours, i spend 6 hours for trying to figure out what the problem was.

It was just a capital B, I did the first request with: ExternalLoginCallback And the second with: ExternalLoginCallBack

I'm happy and sad at the same time, haha!

Comment: Had the same problem with 400 bad request. Had to modify the ValidateClientRedirectUri code in the ApplicationOAuthProvider class.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that this doesn't actually have anything to do with .NET. In your code, you have

```
ReturnUrl = "http://localhost:25806/Facebook/ExternalLoginCallback"
```

However, the value in the query url you provided is

```
http://localhost:18774/vacatures/ExternalLoginCallBack
```

In your Facebook application's settings on facebook.com, there is a field for return URI. This value is probably different from what you have here. You must change one of them so that they match. That is what the error is explaining.

Comment: The link i used there is http://localhost and that one worked for my asp.net mvc C# 4 project, i did change it to http://localhost:25806 but it didn't work

Comment: What happens if you enter the full URL?

Comment: Do you have a trailing slash in this URL? If so, you need the trailing slash in both of the calls to the Oauth process

Comment: Upon looking at your question the value in your query uri is http://localhost:18774/vacatures/ExternalLoginCallBack. I'm fairly certain that your URLs dont match up and that is causing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem before.
The main mistake was that in redirect_uri, I didn't add **`/`** at the end. If the application is in test mode and Facebook says:

> If only development mode is enabled, all redirects http://localhost are resolved automatically and they don't need to be added here.",

then you should add **`/`** to your redirect_uri (http://localhost:3000 **/**).
If this is developer mode, don't forget to add your redirect_uri   to "Valid OAuth redirect URIs". And redirect_uri in request must be the same, that in "Valid OAuth redirect URIs".